# How to access grandchild viewmodel from parent viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

In my webapp i am creating three viewmodel which are nested like first viewmodel is parent of second , second is parent of third. now if i want to display value of third view model it is giving me error that it is not define . In my code `LoanRateViewModel` is parent whose child is `Term` and `Tier` is child of `Term`.

```
function Tier(data){
    var self = this;
    self.tierValue = ko.observable(data.tierValue || "");
    self.rate = ko.observable(data.rate || "121212");
    self.simplerate = ko.observable(data.simplerate || "121212");
    self.compoundrate = ko.observable(data.compoundrate || "12212");
    } 

function Term(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Tiers = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.loanterm = ko.observable(data.loanterm || "12");
    self.termIdentifier = ko.observable(data.termIdentifier || "12");
};
```

here is jsfiddle link [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sohimohit/b81mjt9k/8/)

How can i call the grand child is it possible through knockout js ?

Comment: You can't skip levels just like that - how do you know which grandchild to show? You must know it's parent. So try using something like: `LoanRateViewModel.Terms()[i].Tiers()` where `i` is the index of `Tier's` parent.

Comment: You can use a computed to build an array of all tiers by enumerating all Terms.  Even if you did that, you have a problem with  `<a data-bind="click: addTier">Add Fields</a>`.  Which Term do you have the Tier to ?

Comment: If it is accessed through a ui call you can pass in the event and use a ko.contextFor(element) and in that model you have access to its parent and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unfortunately not in the code you posted*, but in the fiddle.

What you want is certainly possible, though as mentioned in comments you'd need proper nesting to reach grand-children, because they will always be in the context of a certain parent (`Term`). [I've (mostly) fixed your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b81mjt9k/11/), fixing issues until there were no errors left. Some things that would answer your "question" are:

- Make sure you properly close DOM elements (e.g. `table` and `tbody`);
- Make sure you refer to `$root` for methods that are on the root (e.g. `addTier`);
- In tables, make sure each row has equal number of cells (or use `colspan`), or your results will look weird.

<sub>* It'd be nice if you edit your question, and included the relevant (preferably well-formatted) code, so the question can remain useful for others with a similar problem.</sub>